# PHP not all post data is received on server

Tags: php, apache

I am posting data with a size of approximately 200KB to my server running PHP 5.3.3.7.
The data is actually a JavaScript object with nested properties,
in the request it looks something like this: `myObject[prop1][subprop1][key] = 5`.

However, all data isn't received on the server. The last part of the posted data is cut off. `max_post_size` is set to 80MB so that shouldnt be the issue. I have compared the request form data with the data that is accessable through $_POST, and there are lots of data missing.

PHP version is 5.3.3.7.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Show us some code. Especially how you're handling the sending and receiving.

Comment: Any chance the data isn't encoded correctly? Are you letting the browser POST or using cURL or something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said you use PHP 5.3.3, but maybe this is not quite right? Since PHP 5.3.9 there is a new setting `max_input_vars` that limits number of `POST` (and `GET`, and `COOKIE`, and so on, and so on) variables one can pass to a script.

If I am right, then it is enough to adjust it in `php.ini`, `VirtualHost definition`, or in `.htaccess` (`ini_set` will not work since the `POST` is already trimmed after your script started)

This setting was introduced for security reasons, so be cautious:
http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/171-PHP-Vulnerability-May-Halt-Millions-of-Servers.html

Comment: I increased max_input_vars and my problem is solved. The only answer which only looked into solving the problem instead of finding workarounds.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From client side try to use jQuery and convert you data to JSON, before send POST to server

```
   $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://someurl.com',
        data: JSON.stringigy(youJsObject),
        success: function(data) {
            // processing data from server
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry but you misunderstood my question, there is nothing wrong with the request. It's the server that doesn't receive all props.